# No matching function for call without non-parameter constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

We have a template class containing another class containing template object with parameterized constructor.

```
template<class T>
class A {
public:

    class B {
    public:
        T object;

        B(T obj) {
            this->object = obj;
        }
    };

    T foo(T obj) {
        B *b = new B(obj);
        return b->object;
    }
};
```

Also we have a class of object we want as foo() parameter:

```
class Item {
public:
    int value;

//  Item() {}
//  Non-parameter constructor. Within works fine

    Item(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

> **Notice:** Within non-parameter constructor `Item() {}` code run flawlessly, but for some reason constructor always runs once without being called explicitly.

And here goes `main()` to call `a.foo()`:

```
    A<Item> a;
    Item item(5);

    cout << a.foo(item).value;  //expected: 5
```

Eventually we got an error like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Item::Item()'
    B(T obj) {
             ^
```

> **Question:** How to made code with this structure work without having non-parameter constructor in `Class Item {}`?

- What is the reason of that structure?
- I code implementation of **doubly linked list** and simplified such error from it into this code above.

> HINT: I want to make code work without changing `Class Item {}` definition because I'm provider of `Class A` and I want to resolve this case particularly.

### SOLVED

> Error solved by using member initialization list. Thanks to [Ulrich Eckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968182/ulrich-eckhardt).

```
B(T obj) {
    this->object = obj;
}
//wrong

B(T obj): object(obj) {}
//correct
```

Comment: If you remove the `template` part, do you still get the same error? I'd guess that the single parameter constructor that you provided simply hides the default copy constructor that the compile would generate.

Comment: Use member list initialization.